# LyX: includepdf command inserts a blank page before actual page with no title environment

Tags: lyx, pdfpages

When I go to include a PDF, My output always seems to output a blank page before the actual included PDF.

I checked my environments, and to no avail, there is nothing in the environment to cause this blank page to appear.

Is this a bug? Does anyone have a fix?

Edit: Here's a snippet for LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{extarticle}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,
  tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}
\begin{document}
\noindent 
\includepdf[
    pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]
    {\string"/Volumes/path-to-pdf/
     \string"\string"path-to-pdf\string"}
\end{document}
```

Here's the test lyx file:

```
#LyX 2.1 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 474
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass extarticle
\begin_preamble
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman Times
\font_sans Default
\font_typewriter Default
\font_math auto
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts true
\font_sc true
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format pdf4
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\float_placement H
\paperfontsize 12
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\pdf_bookmarks true
\pdf_bookmarksnumbered false
\pdf_bookmarksopen false
\pdf_bookmarksopenlevel 1
\pdf_breaklinks false
\pdf_pdfborder false
\pdf_colorlinks false
\pdf_backref false
\pdf_pdfusetitle false
\papersize letterpaper
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 0
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 0
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 0
\use_package stmaryrd 0
\use_package undertilde 0
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date true
\justification false
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 1in
\topmargin 1in
\rightmargin 1in
\bottommargin 1in
\secnumdepth -2
\tocdepth 2
\paragraph_separation skip
\defskip medskip
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes true
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\noindent
\begin_inset External
    template PDFPages
    filename /Path-to-pdf/
    extra LaTeX "pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Please keep in mind you must insert your own document in "Path-to-pdf" in the LyX file.

Comment: Since not everyone use LyX, we'd like to see some code. For example the code generated by having Lyx save the file to Portable LaTeX.

Comment: and even for those who do use LyX, there is no .lyx file to test. Please create a minimal example: http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: @daleif I've updated the content above.

Comment: @scottkosty see above.

Comment: I'm guessing the `\noindent`, remember includepdf in placing the stuff in the background, so the noindent is not needed. But it adds "something"  to the current page which is then non empty and has the be shipped out before including the pdf

Comment: @daleif I understand that, so how do I transcribe that application into LyX?

Comment: No idea, I never use LyX